# One of methods doesn't work correctly when i call it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make two checks in log files and display the result. Separately methods work correctly, but when I run all code method **hit_unique_check** always return "*PASS: All hits are unique.*". For two of three **.log** files this result is incorrect.

```
import os


class ReadFiles:

    def __init__(self):
        self.current_file = ""
        self.shoot_from = "Shoot from"
        self.hit_player = "Hit player"

    def equally_check(self):
        shoot_from_list = []
        hit_player_list = []
        for line in self.current_file:
            if self.shoot_from in line:
                shoot_from_list.append(line)
            elif self.hit_player in line:
                hit_player_list.append(line)
        if len(shoot_from_list) == len(hit_player_list):
            print(" PASS: Shoots and hits are equal.\n")
        else:
            print(" FAIL: Shoots and hits are NOT equal.\n")

    def hit_unique_check(self):
        unique_hit_list = []
        duplicates = []
        for line in self.current_file:
            if self.hit_player in line:
                unique_hit_list.append(line)
            else:
                continue
        for i in unique_hit_list:
            if unique_hit_list.count(i) > 1:
                duplicates.append(i)
                print(i)
            else:
                continue
        if len(duplicates) < 1:
            print(" PASS: All hits are unique.\n")
        else:
            print(" FAIL: This hits are duplicated.\n")

    def run(self):
        for file in os.listdir():
            if file.endswith(".log"):
                print(f"Log file - {file}")
                self.current_file = open(f"{file}", 'rt')
                print(self.current_file.readlines, f"")
                self.equally_check()
                self.hit_unique_check()
                self.current_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run = ReadFiles()
    run.run()
```

I run my python code, but result always the same: "*PASS: All hits are unique.*". For some files it must be "*FAIL: This hits are duplicated.*". I'm not sure that problem in the method **hit_unique_check**, and have no idea what to do.

Can you explain me, how I can make this method working correctly not only separately?

Comment: What's the point of `print(self.current_file.readlines, f"")`? If you are trying to print all lines in the file, then you need to _call the function_. Note that after yu call the function, your file handle will be exhausted and your loops will no longer work

Comment: This is also the reason you encounter your bug -- once the file has been iterated through once, you need to reopen it or seek to the start if you want to iterate over it again. This would be very evident if you [did any debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), especially if you [stepped through your code in a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: Perhaps you should read the file into a list in `run`, and then reuse the list in your check functions.  Or, perhaps your check functions should do one line at a time, so you only go through the file once.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this organization.  Each function has one task, to evaluate and return its result.  It's up to the caller to decide what to do with the result.  Also note that I'm using counters instead of lists, since you don't really care what the lists contain.  Also note the use of defaultdict, to avoid having to do repeated searches of your hit list.

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

class ReadFiles:

    def __init__(self):
        self.shoot_from = "Shoot from"
        self.hit_player = "Hit player"

    def equally_check(self, lines):
        shoot_from = 0
        hit_player = 0
        for line in lines:
            if self.shoot_from in line:
                shoot_from += 1
            elif self.hit_player in line:
                hit_player += 1
        return shoot_from == hit_player

    def hit_unique_check(self, lines):
        unique_hit_list = defaultdict(int)
        for line in lines:
            if self.hit_player in line:
                unique_hit_list[line] += 1
        duplicates = 0
        for k,v in unique_hit_list.items()
            if v > 1:
                duplicates += 1
                print(k)
        return not duplicates

    def run(self):
        for filename in os.listdir():
            if filename.endswith(".log"):
                print(f"Log file - {filename}")
                lines = open(filename, 'rt').readlines()
                print(lines)
                if self.equally_check(lines):
                    print(" PASS: Shoots and hits are equal.\n")
                else:
                    print(" FAIL: Shoots and hits are NOT equal.\n")
                if self.hit_unique_check(lines):
                    print(" PASS: All hits are unique.\n")
                else:
                    print(" FAIL: This hits are duplicated.\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run = ReadFiles()
    run.run()
```

You could even replace the loop in `hit_unique_check` with a counter:

```
from collections import Counter
...
    def hit_unique_check(self,lines):
        unique_hit_list = Counter(lines)
        for k,v in unique_hit_list,items():
...
```